# Combine some excels as sheets into one excel

Tags: excel

Suppose, I have three Excel files, say `Excel_1`, `Excel_2`, `Excel_3`, how to quickly combine them to a new `Excel` with three sheets such that, `sheet_1` is `Excel_1`; `sheet _2` is `Excel_2`; `sheet_3` is `Excel_3`.

Comment: Do you want to do this by hand, or with a VBA formula? There's a quick way of moving a tab to another sheet, but it still requires you to move each one separately.

Comment: sorry, do not use the VBA, and just like combining pdfs in adobe acrobat

Comment: how many workbooks you have to combine? I can work on a javascript code to combine all files to one single workbook

Comment: @GowthamShiva We can suppose a lot of....but it seems we have to finish one by one if just simply use excel itself.

Answer (score 0):

Manually speaking:

Open all Excel files.

Right-click on the sheet, select "move or copy" and in the new window select your Excel-file which shall hold the sheets. Click Ok.

Comment: but you still need do this one by one, if there are a lot of files, is there any quick way to achieve the result?

Answer (score 0):

Just Drag the sheets to new excel file.

Open all the excel sheets you want to merge, then at the bottom left you can see the sheet name, drag that sheet and point to the minimised excel icon in the taskbar, then point to the excel sheet you want to paste the sheet, when that sheet comes up just release the mouse. All done